# Display image inside email

Tags: php

Below is my function working fine with one issue it doesn't display image in the email why?
if I send image with attachment then it displaying not inside the message

PLease help

```
public function send_email() {
    //getting form data 
    $username =$this->input->post('username');
    $from     = $this->input->post('from');
    $to       = $this->input->post('to');
    $subject  = $this->input->post('subject');
    $message  = '<html><head></head><body><img src="https://www.freedigitalphotos.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/facebook-image-compression-570x200.jpg" width="200px" height="200px;" />"'.$this->input->post('message').'" </body>';
    //email config 
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'XXXXX@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'XXXXX';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $this->load->library('email',$config);  
    $this->email->initialize($config);   
    $this->email->from($from, $username);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    if ($this->email->send()) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
        echo"mail send successfully";
    } else { 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
        $debug=$this->email->print_debugger();  
        //echo $debug;die;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Lots of people have their mail readers configured to not show remote images.

Comment: Please tell me how to display it

Comment: You cannot do anything to show them by default. Its a part of security in email clients. The user has to click on display images / display images always when viewing the email.

Comment: this link may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846167/how-to-display-an-image-in-email-in-codeigniter